# To default ngix config, add subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I have the default nginx config. I want to make it so when they go to my `url/SUBDIR/` it will load one of my ports. I added this to my default config:

```
    location /do {
            # blah
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
```

However when I go to my URL `/do` it says to me:

> Cannot GET /do

Here is the full config -

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /do {
                # blah
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #       deny all;
        #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: Assuming `nginx -t` was done and the config was reloaded after the change. Do the logs have anything?

Comment: Is there any additional headers that your upstream is expecting as you are only passing the `IP` and `Host`?

Comment: Thanks @ShawnC. I actually didnt restart stop then start nginx, should I do that? What does `ngix -t` do? Does that reload the config?

Comment: @ShawnC. I reloaded it with `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload` however still no luck. :(

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` shows if your configuration is valid. Should run that after a change and before a reload or restart.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnC. I did that, but accesing `/do` still giving me this get error :(

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Thanks @ShawnC. for your persistance. I checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log` but it is empty.